# Regex to match numeric pattern

Tags: regex, awk, grep

I am trying to match specific numeric pattern from the below list.
My requirement is to match only `report.20150325` to `report.20150331`. Please help.

```
report.20150319
report.20150320
report.20150321
report.20150322
report.20150323
report.20150324
report.20150325
report.20150326
report.20150327
report.20150328
report.20150329
report.20150330
report.20150331
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple to match 25 to 31 use regex `2[5-9]|3[01]`

Here is complete regex

```
(report\.201503(2[5-9]|3[01]))
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hK3tV2/1)

Explanation of `2[5-9]|3[01]`

```
2 followed by a single character in the range between 5 and 9
OR
3 followed by 0 or 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like so: `^report\.201503(2[5-9]|3[01])$/gm` (built using [this](http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range) tool).

It should match the reports you are after, as shown [here](https://regex101.com/r/rP2qF3/1).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to print the lines which falls between the lines which matches two separate patterns (*including the lines which matches the patterns*).

```
$ sed -n '/^report\.20150325$/,/^report\.20150331$/p' file
report.20150325
report.20150326
report.20150327
report.20150328
report.20150329
report.20150330
report.20150331
```

Comment: `awk '/report.20150325/{f=1}/report.20150331/{print;f=0}f' file`

Comment: remember to anchor your REs and escape metachars you want taken literally.

Answer (score 0):

A regexp match isn't always the right approach. Here you are asking to match a string followed by a number so use a string and numeric comparisons:

```
$ awk -F'.' '$1=="report" && ($2>=20150325) && ($2<=20150331)' file
report.20150325
report.20150326
report.20150327
report.20150328
report.20150329
report.20150330
report.20150331
```